# Как отформатировать текст к нужному виду?

Tags: css

Привет! Подскажите, как привести текст к соответствующем макету: 
Может быть, вы хотите 
подобрать завтрак
 для себя?

Без использования br и навешивания дополнительных стилей для ссылки. Какие есть варианты?

```css
.b-404__block-info {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 31px;
  margin-left: 19px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #b9b9b9;
}
a {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fdd32a;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-404__block-info">
  <p>Может быть, вы хотите <a href="" title="подобрать завтрак">подобрать завтрак</a> для себя</p>
  <p>Или, возможно, вы ищете ближайшего<a href="" title="продавца">продавца</a>завтрака?</p>
  <p>И, кстати, наш завтрак - это продукт, который производятся<a href="" title="с 1990 года">с 1990 года.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: ширину для абзаца установи

Comment: @Grundy нет, такое пробовал, почему-то к примеру у первой p "хотите" переносится на следующую строку.

Comment: ну так все зависит от ширины которая устанавливается

Comment: например при ширине 435px первый абзац выглядит именно так как нужно

Comment: @Grundy да выставлял я ширину. Почему к примеру в консоли ссылка показывает, как-будто соседние слова тоже относятся к ней.

Comment: что значит _в консоли ссылка показывает, как-будто соседние слова тоже относятся к ней_?

Comment: @Grundy извиняюсь, сейчас такого уже нет. Ширину прописал, но вид принимает все равно не такой, "хотите" переносится на строку с ссылкой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39943/discussion-between-grundy-and-drtvader).